# Что значит "языковая картина мира - схема восприятия действительности"?

Tags: семантика, лексикология

"Языковая картина мира - зафиксированная в языке и специфическая для данного языкового коллектива схема восприятия действительности".

То есть мы схематизируем и классифицируем в языке то, что восприняли? И эта схема так же влияет на наше восприятие.

Мне кажется, я что-то поняла не правильно, т. к. пример привести не могу вообще. То есть пример, который иллюстрирует процесс схематизации.

Comment: Примеры есть только такие: антропоморфный характер языковой картины мира
- в русском языке: под носом, под рукой, рукой подать (близко)
- в итальянском языке: avere a / alla/ sotto mano - иметь под рукой; essere alla mano - рукой подать, быть доступным.


Антропоцентрические матафоры: 
- подошва горы, устье реки, горный хребет, рукав реки - пространство описывается, очеловечивается с помощью антропоморфного кода.
- sbocco (выход), foce - устье (реки).
Описаны так же примеры с семантикой движения в русском языке. Но я не уверена, что это то, т к не понимаю, где тут схема, классификация

Comment: Ну пример можно с цветами привести. У нас есть синий, голубой итд. В английском это все blue. И это две разные языковые картины мира. Но английский можно перевести на русский и наоборот, так что все языковые картины мира сводимы друг к другу и смысла в них не так много.

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто не поняла, почему она пишет "схема восприятия". Почему схема. Как выглядит эта схема. Вот у меня подобные примеры тоже, и я не вижу в этом схему. Точнее не понимаю, как эти все примеры иллюстрируют схему восприятия.

Comment: Или она пишет: " картина мира - классифицирующая схема действительности". Я не понимаю, что за схема действительности. У действительности что, есть какая-то схема?  Не понимаю этого

Comment: Хорошо, что вы не понимаете этого нагромождения заумных общих фраз. Да и какая разница, что  конкретно там кто-то пишет. Нам бы несколько иллюстративных примеров, а дальше сами додумаем. В науке есть даже поговорка "теории приходят и уходят, а примеры остаются".